# Parser for multiple data types without returning object

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I'm building a parser for some data that's given as XML, something similar to:

Get file in path `%windir%\system32\calc.exe` and retrieve it's `CreationTime`

The small problem that I have is that the type of object that I'm retrieving (`FileInfo` in example above) and the data type of the property I'm reading (`CreationTime` which is `DateTime` in example above) isn't always the same.

For example: on a `FileInfo` object alone I could be asked for:

- `bool Exists`
- `DateTime CreationTime`
- `DateTime LastWriteTime`
- `long Size`
- `Version Version`

Other object types could be things like `FolderInfo`, `RegistryKey` and `RegistryValue`

With that in mind, I created the following code:

```
public interface IPropertyRetriever<out T>
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Property Property { get; }

    public T RetrieveProperty();
}

public enum Property
{
    Count,
    DateCreated,
    DateModified,
    RegistryKeyExists,
    RegistryValueExists,
    Size,
    Value,
    Version
}

public class FilePropertyRetriever<T> : IPropertyRetriever<T>
{
    public FilePropertyRetriever(string name, Property property, string path, bool is64Bit)
    {
        Name = name;
        Property = property;
        Path = path;
        Is64Bit = is64Bit;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public Property Property { get; }

    public string Path { get; }

    public T RetrieveProperty()
    {
        var file = ...
        // Do something to retrieve FileInfo, 
        // assumes if it got to code below FileInfo.Exists is true

        return (T) (object) (Property switch
        {
            Property.Count => file.Exists,
            Property.DateCreated => file.CreationTime,
            Property.DateModified => file.LastWriteTime,
            Property.Size => file.Length,
            Property.Version => Version.TryParse(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path).ProductVersion,
                out var version)
                ? version
                : null
        });
    }
}
```

I know that my `T RetrieverProperty()` method isn't exactly very good programming - I'm telling my method what type I want it to return when in fact it knows already and using generics to cast to the correct type (and boxing it first if `DateTime`/`long`/`int`), but I really can't think of a better way of doing this.

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

PS: The reason why the `RetrieveProperty()` accepts no parameters and instead uses properties is because the device where the object is created and where the method are run is not the same, the object is serialised and sent over.

Comment: why can't you just deserialize your data into a class that has the properties in the Property enum?  If the caller knows the Property it wants then it can just use the appropriate property

Comment: @TimRutter The caller is local, not remote. Server serialises class, sends it to client. Client deserialises it, retrieves property based on given data, does something with it. Knowing the data type rather than dealing with `object` is important. I feel like retrieving every single possible property and loading it to a class when I'm only interested in one property is false economy.

Answer (score 0):

why can't IPropertyRetriever just be this:

```
public interface IPropertyRetriever
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public int Count {get;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;}
    public DateTime DateModified {get;}
    public bool RegistryKeyExists {get;}
    public bool RegistryValueExists {get;}
    public long Size {get;}
    //etc    
}
```

And call it something different IFileInformation.  Or have different interfaces returned for different objects with a base interface as not all the above properties are relevant to all objects.

Comment: Because not all objects have a `DateCreated` or a `Version` or a `Size` (among others). And because I'm interested in a *single* property, feels like loading every single possible property into a class to just use one when I already _know_ exactly which one I want feels ... unnecessary.

Comment: The above is an interface not a class and so you don't have to load all the data at all.  And see my second comment, you return different interfaces depending on the thing you are deserializing

Comment: given you've got the bit saying "// Do something to retrieve FileInfo," aren't you just loading everything there anyway?

Comment: Thirdly, you have a property enum which means you could easily ask for size on a object that doesn't have size so I don't see how your solution is any better than what I've got above.  I think you're over thinking this a bit

Comment: Doing that would also imply making every property nullable for example... And as for asking for size on an object that doesn't have size, you can see from the code above I throw if the property is not supported for that object.

Comment: I think that having a base interface with just the common properties across all objects (`Name` and `Count`) and then more concrete interfaces for `File`, `Folder` etc still leaves me with the same problem: I have to cast from `IBaseInterface` to `IConcreteInterface` in order to load read the required property.

Comment: why is that a problem exactly? and why would the properties need to be nullable? Where do you throw? I see no throw in your code. You seem to imply that having to cast to an interface you are expecting is more of a problem then calling a property via an enum with all the boxing/unboxing problems and the fact that you can ask for a property on an object that does not have it